# One Two Three Four Five

Tags: javascript

The console.log does not log after the return inside the **self.$show** variable:

```
     filterDates: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.startDay = self.$startDate.val();
            self.endDay = self.$endDate.val();

       if (self.endDay == 0) {
                return false
            } else {
                self.$targets = $('#mixContainer').find('.mix');
                self.$show = self.$targets.filter(function() {
                    self.date = self.$targets.attr('data-date');
                    return (self.date >= self.startDay) && (self.date <= self.endDay);
                    console.log("this DOES NOT log")
                });
                console.log(self.$show +"this WILL log");   // says [object, Object]
                self.parseFilters();
                return self.$show;                          //THIS DOES NOT WORK 
                console.log(self.$show +"THIS DOES NOT log")
            } 
         }
```

I'm not understanding why it does not log nor is is causing any errors. I have the script in context here: http://codepen.io/EricBintner/pen/LNPrZQ

Comment: After a return statement, the function will die.

Comment: The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Comment: I'll just delete the original, sorry. Clearly not helping the community.

Comment: This in now 100% disassociated from anything related to any question I have ever asked.

Comment: If it's not related to anything, delete the question, or just leave it as it was. Changing it to rubbish helps the community even less

Comment: I would love to delete this question, however that is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the return statement stops execution of that function. When you return, the return value is given to the function that called filterDates, which then continues executing.

## Example

Consider the following script:

```
function f1(arg){
    console.log(arg);
    arg = arg*2;
    return arg;
    console.log("arg after return: "+arg);
}

function caller(){
    console.log(f1(2));
}

caller();
```

Now, the console output will look like this:

```
2
4
```

You'll notice that there's no statement like `arg after return: 4` in there. That's because that call comes after the eturn statement, which moves execution from `f1` back to caller.

## Your case

In your specific question, you should move the `console.log` call before your return statement:

```
console.log("Now this DOES log! :-)")
return (self.date >= self.startDay) && (self.date <= self.endDay);
```

Comment: Ah ha. Thanks. So I'm still searching for the problem then.

Comment: You should move the `console.log` call to before the return statement.

Comment: "This question may already have an answer here:" Actually no. It has not. And that only make this confusing. And I cannot delete this post. It's just bad for everyone and nobody is concerned about deleting this for the betterment of the community.

Comment: This says I am correct to link to a different question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312172/offer-a-bounty-and-add-details-to-a-question

Comment: @Eric_B What was the question you asked, that brought you here?

Comment: Why the return was not working. You answered that. Thank you. That is a very basic thing I did not understand. Knowing that, this has absolutely nothing to do with my other question. There's just no way to fix the incorrect "duplicate question" flag and no way to ever ask a related question and give it context with the fear of being flagged by somebody who sees a link to another post and assumes it's the same problem. I made sure to make this as stupid as possible because there is apparently no way to delete a post and was hoping an admin would realize that.